# spring boot jquery ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, spring-boot

I want to submit my jsp using jquery ajax form submit. While submitting browser showing **"Content type 'application/json;charset=utf-8' not supported"**

```
   var form = $('#encryptForm');
            $(function() {
               $('button[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
                  //Prevent default submission of form
                  e.preventDefault();

                  $.post({
                     url : 'encrypt',
                     dataType: "json",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     data : form.serialize(),
                     success : function(res) {
                         console.log(res)
                     }
                  })
               });
            });



  <form id="encryptForm" name="encryptForm" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>User Fields</legend>
                    <p>
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="encryptData" >{"mid":"MID-NehoT","message":"hello"}</textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>



       @RequestMapping(value = "/encrypt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Response post(@RequestBody Request request) {

            return null;
        }



@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Request {
    private String mid;
    private String message;



    @JsonCreator
    public Request(String mid, String message) {
        this.mid = mid;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMid() {
        return mid;
    }

    public void setMid(String mid) {
        this.mid = mid;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining  `dataType: "json",`  but passing  `form.serialize()` which is not JSON

Pass JSON like this

```
$('button[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
  //Prevent default submission of form
  e.preventDefault();
  var json = {"mid":"MID-NehoT","message":"hello"}
  $.post({
     url : 'encrypt',
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data : JSON.stringify(json),
     success : function(res) {
         console.log(res)
     }
  })
});
```

I also assume your Request object contains field  `mid` and `message`

Comment: This  might help   http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/77132-json-httpmediatypenotsupportedexception

Comment: Also pls add Request class in Question

Comment: Request class added

Answer (score 1):

Either remove @RequestBody from your code like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/encrypt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response post() {
    return null;
}
```

or use Map instead like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/encrypt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response post(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestData) {
   return null;
}
```

Comment: No I want to post with the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.post({
     url : 'encrypt',
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data : $('#txtEn').val(),
     success : function(res) {
         console.log(res)
     }
  })
```

i just passed as normal string.